# Bitcoin nonstandard tx

Tags: bitcoind

I had difficulty broadcasting my non- standard transaction as every node rejects it, have been all around google, every solution I see says download the entire blockchain, which I spent 4 weeks downloading, now am done finally a node still unable to broadcast my non- standard transaction.
Noticed that eligus mine such transaction.
My question is, how do I broadcast such transaction using my node.

Comment: What is non-standard about your transaction? Also, this might be a better fit for bitcoin.se

Comment: I keep getting missing inputs error commands

Comment: Well, _does_ your transaction have inputs?

Comment: Also tried with lower free then it says missing input.

Comment: Now that I have a full node running is there no faster way I can get it done it still refuse to relay my tx